# angular directive to style a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to style a checkbox with an angular directive and I came up with a simple solution. My idea is to have in HTML an input like this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="abc1"/>
```

and I want to create a directive that practically wraps this input inside a label with the class check and adds a div after the input so I can target that div after the input with + from CSS and design on it the states of the input.

So my directive should transform my HTML from what I should previous into this

```
<label class="check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="abc1"/>
    <div></div>
</label>
```

now I created this directive

```
.directive('checkbox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<label><ng-transclude></ng-transclude><div></div></label>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    };
})
```

but it doesn't do the layout I want to achieve, I hope someone can help me showing the way to write the directive in order to transform it into that HTML output.

Comment: Could you add a plunkr to let us play with it?

Comment: here it is

http://plnkr.co/edit/2KSVvDY72G2l2SvMQyB2?p=preview

Comment: I have played a bit with it, manage to get the labe content surrounding, added replace:true, tell me if this can be an starting point http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhecuDp0NoCLbfxm02Xt?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following directive will wrap the input element to achieve the HTML structure that you want.   If the wrapper div is strictly structural and does not contain any directives, then I think it is OK to do this.

```
  app.directive('checkbox', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'C',
          link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
              elem.wrap('<div class="check"></div>');
              elem.after('<div></div>');
          }
      };
  });
```

Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rVfwtOM54k4yX6F1wyIR?p=preview)

Comment: i used this and i get this into the html 

<!-- checkbox: undefined -->

Comment: thank you for this answer, i have used this, the only change is i moved the stuff from the link into the compile function